# Workaround for StringIndexOutOfBoundsException while testing for certain characters

Tags: java, equals

I'm making an if conditional to test to see if a string given contains 'me' at the end of it.

```
Given     Return
-----     ------
Lame      True
Meant     False
Come      True
etc
```

Right now my code is working perfectly if the string is greater than 2 characters long.

```
public boolean containsLy(String input) {
  String ly = "ly";
  String lastString = input.substring(input.length() - 2);
  if (input.length() < 2) {
      return false;
  }else if (lastString.equals(ly)) {
      return true;
  }else
      return false;
}
```

But whenever the string has 2 characters or less I get this error:

```
StringIndexOutOfBoundsException
```

This is obviously because of a negative number, but I can't think of a workaround for this.

Comment: Answerers, don't suggest using `endsWith`. Sometime people practice and write code to learn and improve their skills.

Comment: Thank you @MarounMaroun.  I am taking Java 1 currently, so I would appreciate more of a theoretical approach instead of a way to make my code simpler with other things

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to return `false` if the `length` of the input is inferior than 2, you can made the check before trying to perform the `substring` operation on your input.

```
public boolean containsLy(String input) {
  if (input == null || input.length() < 2) {
      return false;
  }
  else {
     String ly = "ly";
     String lastString = input.substring(input.length() - 2);
     if (lastString.equals(ly)) {
       return true;
     }
     else {
       return false;
     }
  }
}
```

Or more simple :

```
public boolean containsLy(String input) {
      if (input == null || input.length() < 2) {
          return false;
      }
      else {
         String ly = "ly";
         String lastString = input.substring(input.length() - 2);
         return lastString.equals(ly);
      }
    }
```

Or, to get rid of all the if/else variables stuff (thanks to @Ingo) :

```
public boolean containsLy(String input) {
      return input != null 
             && input.length() >= 2
             && input.substring(input.length() - 2).equals("ly");
}
```

Comment: +1 for solving the problem and not suggesting alternative solution.

Comment: Would +1 if I had enough rep :)
Worked perfectly!  I didn't know that I could include variables in conditionals exclusively as well, so that's a great help!

Comment: @TaylorTDHouse You wouldn't even need a variable, you could as well just write the expression `input.substring(input.length() - 2).equals(ly)

Answer (score 2):

How about checking like this

```
boolean endsWithMe = "myteststring".endsWith("me");
```

If you are doing it for practice then:

Pseudo code:

```
 if length of the given string < 2 then return false
 else substring from index length - 2 to length equals "me"
```

Comment: Was just about to answer with the exact same suggestion of `endsWith()`. Just like yesterday! :)

Comment: @R.J We meet again ;)

Answer (score 0):

Don't reinvent the wheel. Just use `String#endsWith()`

By the way, it is remarkable that you already found out **why** it didn't work the way you did it. But still, you first try to take the substring, and only then you test if it is even possible. Why?

Answer (score 0):

workaround is simple.. check for the string length before performing substring of it or use the `indexOf("me")` to get the index and use the length to see if it is the in the position `length-2`.